# Given $W_k =f(W_{k-1})$ find $W_n= f(W_0,n)$ for specific case

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am essentially trying to create a formula to a baseline for weight loss for me given $N$ days from the beginning. I have worked out that for any given day:

$W_{k} = (\frac{349}{350})W_{k-1} + (\frac{22}{35})$

I would like to get the equation for $W_{n} = f(W_{0},n)$

If I did my math correctly, $W_{n}$ should approach $220$ as $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: you probably want an answer of the form $W_n = f(n)*W_0$

Comment: You're right in the fact that I'm asking for a function with incorrect parameters but I probably want it in the form of $W_{n} = f(W_{0},n)$ since I want to be able to input both a starting weight and an number of days since the beginning

Comment: @Alex ?? Already $W_1$ is **not** of this form.

Comment: Your answer is exactly of the form I gave

Comment: @Alex No. If you can write $n\mapsto a^n(W_0-b)+b$ as $n\mapsto f(n)W_0$, just call me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: There exists some $(\alpha,\beta)$ such that the relation in your post can be rewritten as $W_k-\beta=\alpha\cdot(W_{k-1}-\beta)$. Hence $W_k=\alpha^k\cdot(W_0-\beta)+\beta$ for every $k$.

(Not necessary to solve the question but:) Note that if $(W_k)$ converges then its limit is $\beta$ (and $|\alpha|\leqslant1$ if $W_0\ne\beta$).

Comment: I will attempt to solve with that hint tomorrow and mark it as answered if I can solve it. Thanks,

Comment: There is a small typo in your equation, the subscript of $W$ on the right should be $k-1$.

Comment: @Ian Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: α = 349/350 , β = 220.

Comment: Yes and yes. Well done.

Comment: Solving for that was much more trivial than I first made it to be. I'm glad you left it up to me to figure it out though. That's the best way to learn.